# dotfiles errors | /Users/marif/.aliases:79: bad option: -t

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, dotfiles

I am pretty new to OSX but everything is almost settled down, I had configured Z and ZSH earlier and lately come to know about paulirish dot files from https://github.com/paulirish/dotfiles and installed it.

Got to see following output when I refresh .bash_profile or .bashrc

```
Last login: Tue May 14 08:41:35 on console
ls
➜  ~  ls
Applications    Downloads       Music           Samsung         dotfiles        log
Desktop         Library         Pictures        Sites           install-deps.sh readme.md
Documents       Movies          Public          bin             js-boilerplate
➜  ~  z
zsh: command not found: z
➜  ~  source ~/.bash_profile
/Users/marif/.aliases:79: bad option: -t
/Users/marif/.aliases:82: bad option: -t
/Users/marif/.functions:37: parse error near `]]'
/Users/marif/.bash_profile:.:9: no such file or directory: /Users/marif/code/z/z.sh
/Users/marif/.bash_profile:15: command not found: shopt
/Users/marif/.bash_profile:26: command not found: complete
\[\e]2;/Users/marif\[\a\]\[\e]1;\]Users/\W\[\a\]marif at   \[\]\w\[\]\[\]\[\]\n$ \[\]
```

I don't know what's going wrong here, would help if somebody point me out to issue persisting in my profile or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh is not bash and when I launch "zsh", I see the same error that you do:

```
[/tmp]:;zsh
ElvisIsAliveAndWell-2% type -t
zsh: bad option: -t
```

These paulirish dot files are meant to be used with bash.  Either use bash or you'll need to port the lines in the dot files that are throwing errors so that they will work in zsh (and if you do this, you can fork or branch or suggest changes to PaulIrish so he can pick up these changes and make them available for other interested folks).

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael, you are right, actually I was using zsh and changing it to bash does all, getting better day by day now on OSX :)